# Full screen fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-fullscreen

I'm making an app where, when the phone is in PORTRAIT orientation I need that the fragment shows the menu bar (with settings shortcuts, and so on), but when it's in LANDSCAPE I need a fullscreen.

So, I've one activity that manage 2 fragments, call Fragment 1 if it's in PORTRAIT, and Fragment 2 if it's in LANDSCAPE. 
Only Fragment 2 need to be in fullscreen.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need 2 fragments.  Just add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to activity in manifest file and add the following to the activity:

```
private int oldOptions;

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        oldOptions = getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
        int newOptions = oldOptions;
        newOptions &= ~View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE;
        newOptions |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        newOptions |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
        newOptions |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE;
        newOptions &= ~View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(newOptions);
        getActionBar().hide();
    }
    else
    {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(oldOptions);
        getActionBar().show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Also the notification bar

Comment: Updated answer for true fullscreen

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `onConfigurationChanged` and manage the Action bar in `Activity`

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if(newConfig.orientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        getActionBar().show();
    }
    else {
        getActionBar().hide();
    }
}
```

Also set `configChanges` in Manifest for this `Activity`

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```